# How to make a div to fit all available width hidden with scroll?

Tags: html, css

I've asked this question before. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40848137/how-to-make-a-div-to-fit-all-available-width-even-hidden-with-scroll) is an original post.
We've found a solution but I would like to ask is there any chance to solve this in another way?

Original [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8cepsL09/) link with that issue.

Could someone explain why element with `display:block;` or even with `dipslay:flex;` or any other display type (except table) does not take the width, hidden under scroll?

It's a bit confusing me.

Comment: because width of window(html) is the 100% width avalaible to start with, one element can overflow but others will only used the initial 100% width. display:table; wich the defaut of <table> can expand and any block child within will fill entire width avalaible and won't mind html width or the horizontal scroll bar on parent

Answer (score 1):

When using width 100% it will want to stretch to the size of its container, if you have more content than space, try adding overflow: scroll; it will add a scrollbar and attempt to keep the width you set it at stable.

```
.pane .body {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

Comment: As a side note, a `<div>` by it's nature is a block element which is already 100% width.